# Make user log out forcefully angular

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, .net-core, jwt

I am using  .Net core web api in backend and Angular in front end.

I am generating JWT token for authentication when user sign in.

But I am not storing that token in Database.

Here from back end, we can make user enable and disabled.

Right now what happened is, let's say in front end user is logged in and from back end if we make user disabled then still user can do actions in front end like updating profile, upload files etc..

What I want is if user is disabled from back end then he can't do any action and if he click on any button where api call is coming then he should get logged out because he is disabled.

I have thought of two approach as per below.

1. Like to expire token immediately once user is disabled but problem is I don't have token.
2. I am planning on use signal R to check if user is disabled or not.

So here I would like to know what should I do further to achieve this kind of functionality.

Also if any other way we have to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: If your backend is not storing the token or their expiration, then you need to check if the user is disabled in your DB (or in some caching layer) on every request and send a response to indicate that the frontend should delete the token/log them out.

Comment: What I'll suggest in this case is to change the status code to 401 for all the request once user is disabled and in angular using http_interceptor check the status code as soon as you get 401 logout the user.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not store issued tokens than you will have to inject some code to jwt configuration (`Configure<ITokenValidationService>` or create a middleware) that will lookup user status by name or other claim. For example you can implement some in-memory blacklist with eviction policy.